# ASP.NET Memory Leak Strange Charts

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to diagnose a memory leak, and I'm getting some strange numbers, perhaps someone can point out why I'm seeing what I'm seeing.

The first step that I performed, was attempting to see where the leak was occurring, in managed or unmanaged space.

I profiled the process, and got the following chart

[image]

According to the various documentation on leak diagnostics, I should see either, the private bytes run away while the "all heaps" don't (indicating an unmanaged leak) or they both run away in parallel, indicating a managed one.

It appears I do have a leak - (chart is CPU+Private Bytes+Managed Heaps).

What is puzzling me - is - why do my managed heaps consume only about 30MB between 9am and just before 5pm (but private bytes grow), then all of a sudden - BOOM my managed heaps jump to 3 gigs consumed?

Why would this happen?

UPDATE:

```
654cf3d8   199671      6389472 System.Web.HttpCacheValidateHandler
719c25e8   559507      6714084 System.Object
654b82e8    95499      6875928 System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection
05e90a24   253641      7101948 System.Web.Mvc.NameValueCollectionValueProvider+ValueProviderResultPlaceholder+<>c__DisplayClass8
654e42e4    97208      7776640 System.Web.HttpWriter
04c2a5c8   264802      8473664 Castle.MicroKernel.BurdenReleaseDelegate
04c2ab68   264813      9533268 Castle.MicroKernel.Burden
06bde0a8   507282     10145640 System.Lazy`1[[System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult, System.Web.Mvc]]
6fb5348c   267697     10707880 System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[System.String, mscorlib]]
654e9388   160209     11535048 System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection
654ad44c   194416     12442624 System.Web.HttpCookieCollection
6fd1abbc   170480     14202840 System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1+Slot[[System.String, mscorlib]][]
654b2204    95203     15613292 System.Web.HttpCachePolicy
06bde010   507282     16233024 System.Func`1[[System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult, System.Web.Mvc]]
719c3a6c   469961     18106904 System.Int32[]
654e87e4    97208     18275104 System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
654e2590    97208     19441600 System.Web.HttpRequest
654e285c    97208     19830432 System.Web.HttpResponse
715fbc80   422170     20264160 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object, mscorlib]]
654e2160    97208     23329920 System.Web.HttpContext
654e9614   388836     23330160 System.Web.HttpValueCollection
719c45c8   919071     47791692 System.Collections.Hashtable
654d5220  4808083    115393992 System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollectionEntry
719bfc20  4849839    116396136 System.Collections.ArrayList
719c4584   105080    119191278 System.Byte[]
70d45bec  9064979    145039664 System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase+NameObjectEntry
719afe88  5391401    175028320 System.Object[]
719c5ed4   919078    237147240 System.Collections.Hashtable+bucket[]
719c2248  7055089    454532758 System.String
```

Ok, so I've run windbg over the crash dump, (!dumpheap -live -stat) and I've found that there are LOT of objects relating to the Http context, which are still held in memory (98,000 after a typical work day in fact).

Can anyone confirm... I shouldn't be seeing this right? There are Types occurring 97,208 times in the log - This means that the HttpRequest/HttpResponse, etc are being held in memory, causing ALOT of leakage.
What could be causing this? I know they're not being stored in the session..my session is set to default timeout, and when inspecting, it only contains 3 small string objects.

Comment: It looks like a lot of instances of `System.Collections.Hashtable`.  It could be on a static variable.  Those aren't scoped to a particular connection.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Running GCroot highlighted the problem. See how there is a `Castle.MicroKernel.Releasers.LifecycledComponentsReleasePolicy` in the reference list?

Castle wasn't being told to release the controller after the request had completed. Mystery solved.

```
0:000> !gcroot 95963d2c
HandleTable:
    00bb12f0 (pinned handle)
    -> 03062490 System.Object[]
    -> 021501dc Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer
    -> 02150200 Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel
    -> 02150304 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[Castle.MicroKernel.ISubSystem, Castle.Windsor]]
    -> 02150af8 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[Castle.MicroKernel.ISubSystem, Castle.Windsor]][]
    -> 02150b74 Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.DefaultDiagnosticsSubSystem
    -> 02150b8c System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.IContainerDebuggerExtension, Castle.Windsor]]
    -> 02150d00 System.Object[]
    -> 02150d30 Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.Extensions.ReleasePolicyTrackedObjects
    -> 02150d3c Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.TrackedComponentsDiagnostic
    -> 02150e04 System.EventHandler`1[[Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.TrackedInstancesEventArgs, Castle.Windsor]]
    -> 02150d54 Castle.MicroKernel.Releasers.LifecycledComponentsReleasePolicy
    -> 02150d84 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Object, mscorlib],[Castle.MicroKernel.Burden, Castle.Windsor]]
    -> 038da530 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.Object, mscorlib],[Castle.MicroKernel.Burden, Castle.Windsor]][]
    -> 9596f3a4 WebController
    -> 9596f9cc System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext
    -> 95965b5c System.Web.HttpContextWrapper
    -> 95964078 System.Web.HttpContext
    -> 95963d2c System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
```

Comment: how do you "tell Castle to release it?" We are experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @JMDenver that depends entirely on how you are hijacking the dependency resolution infrastructure inside your application. For example,  we were using System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBuilder to override the controller factory with our own 'WindsorControllerFactory'. Inside that (during the resolution of a controller) we just had to make sure we hooked up to the HttpRequestMessage.RegisterForDispose, which we delegated to the container's release method.